# Adding zero before single digit value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Trying to add a zero before the value if it's less than 10

```
eg:2001-5-9 as 2001-05-09
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into to_char() for date formatting:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

```
select to_char(foo, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If it's not a date already, cast it accordingly

```
select to_char(foo::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Actually its not for date field..Its integer field

Comment: i dont want to have case statements..anything simple way to append?

Comment: @user3007361 It cannot be an integer field. (it could be the concatenation of the string representations of three integer fields) please reformulate your question.